# ¿Como se guardan en un archivo los elementos dibujados en canvas con tkinter, pero que no sea en formato imagen?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7, canvas

Hola foro aquí nuevamente acudiendo al foro, pues estos días estuve aprendiendo a guardar y abrir archivos con tkinter, pero no encuentro en libros mi problema que tengo que es la siguiente.

Existen muchos ejemplos de dibujar en canvas con tkinter, pero lo que no encuentro es como guardar todos los elementos dibujados en canvas en un archivo y después abrirlo nuevamente si quiero modificar los elementos.

Solo hablan de como guardar y abrir imágenes con PIL, pero el problema es que cuando guardo en ese formato se guarda como imagen y cuando abres el archivo pues claro es una imagen y eso no me sirve, pues quiero que cuando abra el archivo abra como elementos independientes que se pueda ver sus propiedades o atributos que pueda tener, ademas volver a guardar los cambios, porque guardando como imagen pierden todo eso.

Alguna forma de realizar esto, algún método o guardar con alguna exención en especial, pues solo quiero pistas o consultar algún método que conozcan, para seguir investigando y aprendiendo. Gracias

Comment: Tal vez puedas guardar los argumentos de los metódos que dibujan cosas, por ejemplo, si dibujas una linea con `create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)` guardas en un archivo `create_line,0,0,200,100` y para cargarlo lees el archivo y ejecutas cada método en un nuevo canvas.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, voy hacerlo, pero lo que tengo en mente es crear elementos como lineas, circulos, arcos dinamicos que al hacer click con el mouse estos elementos muestren pantallas pequeñas donde pueda cambiar sus atributos. Pues pense que en python solo era cuestion de guardar y volver abrir el archivo guardado y seguir trabajando en el archivo.